# if no name entered or blank it should send warn message and then end

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentworkbook As Workbook
    
    Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Robert Sindo\Desktop\JMI Inventory Analyst Master Files\JYKO\JYKO SKU  Masterlist.xlsm")
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("QB Uploader")
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = InputBox("ASSIGN A NEW NAME:")
    
    If sourceworkbook.Value = "" Then
         MsgBox "There is no data in your selection."
         Exit Sub
      Else
         sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Select
      End If
    
    sourceworkbook.Close
```

Comment: Please improve the code formatting

Comment: Is it the newly added Quickbook that you are trying to rename? Do you want to exit the sub immediately if there is no name, or do you want to close the sourceworkbook first? Why are you selecting `sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Select` when you are closing the workbook after? Please clarify these issues and add more detail, both, by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71370746/edit).

Comment: i tried this also ---> sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("QB Uploader")
result = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name
result = InputBox("ASSIGN A NEW NAME:")

If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled."
  ElseIf result = vbNullString Then
  MsgBox "You does not enter anything"
  End If
  
sourceworkbook.Close                         ------------ it works on cancelling and clicking OK but the problem is it wont rename the name i desired if inputted on the input box .

Comment: Yes sir its newly added sheet. all i want is that if there is no name entered and click OK it will input "no data the title of the sheet will leave to blank" something like that meaning still it will copy the sheet and if cancelled it will also message "cancelled." something like that and it WONT COPY the SHEET Quickbook. i dont want to go to the debug settings when entered blank name and cancel. pls help me im just an amateur and i really want to learn on this.

Answer (score 3):

### Existing or Invalid Sheet Name (Error-Handling)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim currentworkbook As Workbook: Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
    Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Robert Sindo\Desktop\JMI Inventory Analyst Master Files\JYKO\JYKO SKU  Masterlist.xlsm")
    
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Copy After:=currentworkbook.Sheets("QB Uploader")
    ' If copying after the last sheet, rather use the following:
    'sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Copy After:=currentworkbook.Sheets(currentworkbook.Sheets.Count)
    
    sourceworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Dim NewName As String: NewName = InputBox("ASSIGN A NEW NAME:")
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next ' there can be two reasons: existing name and invalid name (emptystring, more than 31 chars...)
        currentworkbook.Sheets(currentworkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = NewName
        ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        currentworkbook.Sheets(currentworkbook.Sheets.Count).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "The name '" & NewName & "' could not be used.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    'Else
         'MsgBox "Sheet renamed.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir it works well! amazing! but can you delete the copied cell sir if ever he cancelled or closed?

Comment: Do you mean delete the newly added worksheet?

Comment: yes sir! delete the one that cancelled or closed. because when it cancelled or closed yes it will prompt the name could not be used but the sheet sir must not be copied. it will only copied after it was named sir

Answer (score 1):

```
UserInput = InputBox("Input some text")

If StrPtr(UserInput) = 0 Then
  MsgBox "You've canceled the input box"
ElseIf UserInput = vbNullString Then
  MsgBox "You does not enter anything"
Else
  Process(UserInput)
End If
```

Comment: Sir i tried this ----> Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = 0 then ..etc and so on but still it will go to the Run Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: i tried this also ---> sourceworkbook.Sheets("Quickbook").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("QB Uploader")
result = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name
result = InputBox("ASSIGN A NEW NAME:")

If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled."
  ElseIf result = vbNullString Then
  MsgBox "You does not enter anything"
  End If
  
sourceworkbook.Close                         ------------ it works on cancelling and clicking OK but the problem is it wont rename the name i desired if inputted on the input box .